# Openbox : make 4 desktops 2x2

Tags: virtual-desktop, openbox

Strangely, my openbox default rc.xml file has keyboard shortcuts for the commands DesktopDown and DesktopUp, but it seems that the only configuration option for the desktops is their number (which is interpreted as a linear setup of all the desktops, and you can navigate only right and left).

I'm very much accustomed to having a 2x2 grid of desktops... Is there any way to do that within openbox ? (I'm open to installing other things. I'm even expecting to have to, I just don't know what.)

Answer (score 7):

Took me a while but now I found a workaround. [openbox.org wiki FAQ](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:FAQ#How_do_I_put_my_desktops_into_a_grid_layout_instead_of_a_single_row.3F) linked to a tiny program (called [setlayout](http://icculus.org/openbox/tools/setlayout.c)) which is doing the job

You have to **compile** it with:

1. `sudo aptitude install libx11-dev`
2. `gcc setlayout.c -o setlayout -lX11`

Call it with: `./setlayout 0 2 2 0`

Comment: I had to play around with this to get the setting I wanted, 1 column, 4 rows.  If you want more than 4 workspaces, there is another setting that needs to be changed elsewhere; I tried `./setlayout 0 3 2 0` to try to identify which was row/column but got a 2x2 grid (not helpful).  It turned out `0 1 4 0` was what I wanted.

Comment: For anyone who finds this using Arch like I did, install `libx11`, as there is no `libx11-dev` available. Still compiles/works fine though.

Comment: also: with xprop https://askubuntu.com/a/285409

Answer (score 2):

**Credit to [strangeqargo](https://superuser.com/users/634200/strangeqargo) who pasted a link to this answer in a comment on the first answer**

As stated in the above, you can avoid having to download, compile, and use `setlayout` by using the `xprop` command.

#### Examples

To get 4 columns x 2 rows:

```
xprop -root -f _NET_DESKTOP_LAYOUT 32cccc -set _NET_DESKTOP_LAYOUT 0,4,2,0
```

Set number of workspaces/desktops to 8:

```
xprop -root -f _NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS 32c -set _NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS 8
```

The exact specification for `_NET_DESKTOP_LAYOUT` is available [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html#id2731226)

This is a lightly edited version of the **[Original answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/285409/14795)**